# My QUERY function is not querying within the date range selected within the WHERE clause. How do I fix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the QUERY function to organize data from a raw data set. I am trying to filter to specific **recruiters** as well as specific  **status  types** from said recruiter. All this is working normally.

I recently wanted to add the ability to pick a specific **date range** to drill down even further. This is where my QUERY breaks. My current formula is below.

I am currently NOT getting any ERROR message. It is almost as if the last piece of the formula is just being ignored! Worth noting that I am trying to use the WHERE clause to combine all these things together.

```
=query('BH Sub Data'!A:H,"select * where 1=1 "&if(A2="All Recruiters",""," AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")&if(A3="All Statuses",""," AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A3&"')&' and B >= date '"&text(A5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"')&' and B <= date '"&text(A7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"',1)"))
```

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEqsH.png)

I blocked out sensitive info partially.

I have tried using different tutorials on youtube/searching the web but have not found a combination of code that seems to fix the issue.

I have also tried messing around with the single and double quotations around to see if my syntax was off. The current code above is the only code that doesn't give me an error.

Comment: Your query is not properly formed. `if(A3="All Statuses"` does not close properly. When true it shows: `select * where 1=1  AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('Anu Arora')` -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- And when false it shows: `select * where 1=1  AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('Anu Arora')  AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('Some Statuses')&' and B >= date '2022-12-15')&' and B <= date '2022-12-18',1)`

Comment: Feels closer to being correct but now I am getting a #VALUE! Error. The IF statement closes properly now I believe--------------------------------------------------------------- `=query('BH Sub Data'!A:H,"select * where 1=1 "&if(A2="All Recruiters",""," AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")&if(A3="All Statuses",""," AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A3&"') ")&"' and B >= date '"&text(A5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&text(A7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"',1)")`

Comment: Try: `AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A3&"') ")&" and B`

Comment: Thanks for helping work towards a solution @ADW !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this:

`=query('BH Sub Data'!A:H,"Select * where 1=1 "&if(A2="All Recruiters",," AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('"&A2&"')")&if(A3="All Statuses",," AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A3&"')")&" AND B>= date '"&text(A5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B<= date '"&text(A7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")`

Comment: Agree, I think that OP meant to have too a `,1` after the last quotation mark in order to have headers included

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! I see a few differences in the query. Just so I understand, was it the headers at the end that was messing it up?

Comment: well the quotes placement was spotty in the original formula.

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
=QUERY('BH Sub Data'!A:H,
 "where 1=1 "&
 IF(A2="All Recruiters",," and lower(A) = '"&LOWER(A2)&"'")&
 IF(A3="All Statuses",,  " and lower(D) = '"&LOWER(A3)&"'")&
 " and B >= date '"&TEXT(A5, "e-m-d")&"' 
   and B <= date '"&TEXT(A7, "e-m-d")&"'", 1)
```

Comment: This one didn't end up working but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @austinlandwerlen updated, try now